# Is it possible to create a GUI with python on the Google Cloud Platform

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to create a web application using python on the google cloud platform. I have followed Google's quick-start guide and completed it.

App currently just prints out text

However, I am struggling to figure out a way to create a gui. I am aware of the python modules tk and tkinter and I have tried to use those with no success. I also saw the warning in the Google Cloud Console about how installed modules only exist for the current instance of the app - but even when installing the module directly before deploying the app - it still throws an import error.

I did some research and followed this guide: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27

**Assuming I didn't miss any steps - would this guide solve my problem? Or is there a better way to create a GUI?**
Any suggestions are encouraged. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

App Engine is web oriented service. Read about it in the [overview](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/an-overview-of-app-engine) and the appropriate gui there would be a web based one.

If you want to have a remote server that will server graphical applications look closer at [Google Cloud Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/) where you can have a VM instance, where you can install and run any application.